# Django form - changing queryset dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simply model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    amount = models.DecimalField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

And I have create view and model form for it

```
class ModelAForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = [
            'type', 'amount', 'product'
        ]
```

And how can I do this:

When user in form choose 'type' - TYPE1 then in 'product' he has all products. And it works now.

But when user choose TYPE2 I want to show him in only few product (e.g. older then one year)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with js. Once the first dropdown is selected, depending on the selected value, I would fire an ajax call to fetch only to selected value related content from backend and update the dropdown for product.

Ajax is good for this case, since it doesnot block other actions in browser and runs async.

Comment: I thought so. But how connect this ajax call with ModelForm. Ajax response should contain pure 'select html' but with product id in value? And it will be fine?

Comment: yes fine. or there is better way: just filter out the products directly in frontend via ajax and show only relevant ones. no ajax call to backend needed, since you have all products in the context in template

Answer (score 0):

1. You need validate your Form, because, even you make Ajax upload, anybody can send you with your Form code any combinations of type and product ids. I don't know is it important for you (did you store order as combinations of type and product and does your product related to types).
   To do this:

   ```
   from django.utils.translations import ugettext_lazy as _

   class ModelAForm(ModelForm):

       # Your code here

       def clean(self):
           cleaned_data = super(ModelAForm, self).clean()
           product_type = cleaned_data.get("type")
           product = cleaned_data.get("product")

           if product.type != product_type:
               msg = _("Wrong product type.")
               self.add_error('product', msg)
   ```
2. If you are looking for dynamic form fields you may look for [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) library that allow you to create dynamic forms, sortering and filtering. As example how your client will select product from plain Django form if you have 10'000 products within this type?